# AngularJS show/hide with a function() call

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is it possible to show/hide an element after a function call that returns a boolean? Scenario is, to show "Ready" when all n-items have an "agreed" flag. If not, show something else. Value of agreed flag is changed with a radio button.

```
$scope.data = [
    {
        title: "Agreement #1",
        agreed: false,
    },
    {
        title: "Agreement #2",
        agreed: false,
    },
];

$scope.ready = function()
{
    var go = true;
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(item, key) {
        go &= item.agreed==true;
      });
    return go;
}
```

Then, calling:

```
<div ng-show="ready()">Go!</div>
<div ng-hide="ready()">Missing the points.</div>
```

Problem with this code: **If all radio buttons are checked**, ie. all values of agreed flag are set to true, the **ready()** is not auto updated.

Comment: Personally, I would code that `ng-show="!ready()"` as `ng-hide="ready()"`, and `&=` might be more efficient, but it is less legible. What's wrong with `if (! item.agreed) return false;`, and `return true` after the loop? That's more legible and probably more efficient. It might even solve your problem. If not, can you dump `$scope.data` and post it, please?

Comment: Thanks for quoting ng-show, ng-hide. I updated the question. The $scope.data dump is correct, as soon as I modify. ie. it contains valid values of true or false status. ready() is designed to be an aggregate of all item[i].agreed when set to true.

Comment: I still don't like that `go &= item.agreed==true;` I might worry about operator precedence. If you don't want to recode it as I suggested, then at least add brackets : `go &= (item.agreed==true);`  or, `go &= item.agreed;`, since you don't need to explicitly check for `true`

Comment: I would look for radio inputs change in controller and execute function on its change which would set some scope.flag variable and just display div with condition if this flag is true with ng-if/ng-show/ng-hide whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the boolean value of agreed to the `ng-model` of the radio button and use `ng-value` for setting true/false for each agreement.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.data = [
    {
        title: "Agreement #1",
        agreed: false,
    },
    {
        title: "Agreement #2",
        agreed: false,
    }
]

$scope.ready = function()
{
    var go = true;
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(item, key) {
        go &= item.agreed==true;
      });
    return go;
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-show="ready()">Go!</div>
<div ng-show="!ready()">Missing the points.</div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Agreement </th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="value in data">
            <td>{{value.title}}</td>
            <td>
                Yes <input type="radio" ng-model="value.agreed" ng-value="true" />
                No <input type="radio" ng-model="value.agreed" ng-value="false"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   
    
    <span>{{data}}</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The trick seems to be in data binding with ng-value="true" and ng-value="false". it works.

Answer (score 1):

i think u missed the data variable square bracket

```
$scope.data = [
    {
        title: "Agreement #1",
        agreed: true,
    },
    {
        title: "Agreement #2",
        agreed: false,
    },
];
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/xWdro1SCUTeLbRVbEMWi?p=preview

Comment: or is there another issue?

Comment: No other issues. That was all due to copying small portion of actual code and trimming. Thanks.